# Cannot run AspectJ CTW application in IntelliJ IDEA without Maven rebuild

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea, aspectj

**EDIT/UPDATE: Delegate IDE build/run actions to maven in IntelliJ settings solve the problem, but how to handle it without it?**

I have the following problem:

I change something in my GetSthAspect class -> Then I run maven clean install  (let's assume I have to always do clean install in my app) -> Run spring app -> And I see error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.demo.aspects.GetSthAspect.aspectOf()Lcom/example/demo/aspects/GetSthAspect;
    at com.example.demo.aspects.A.shouldDoSthAndCallMethodGetSth(A.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.aspects.AspectApp.main(AspectApp.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
  ...
```

Then I stop app -> Again do maven clean install -> Again run app and now everything works fine.

It's always like that when I change something in my GetSthAspect class and I want to see my changes in app. Why is that? Why I have to build app -> run app -> stop app -> again build app and run it in order to my aspects works fine? What should I do to avoid this situation?

**GetSthAspect**

```java
@Aspect
public class GetSthAspect {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GetSthAspect.class);

    @Around("call(* Ent.getSth())")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint  pjp) throws Throwable {
        logger.info("Inside around + 12:52");

        Ent ent = (Ent) pjp.getTarget();
        logger.info("Number: " + ent.getImportantNumber());

        return pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```

**some class**

```java
public class AspectApp {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AspectApp.class);

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String main() {
        logger.info("Method main started + 11:01");

        A a = new A();
        a.shouldDoSthAndCallMethodGetSth(1);
    }

}
```

**A**

```java
public class A {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(A.class);

    public void shouldDoSthAndCallMethodGetSth(Integer a) {
        // ...
        Ent ent = new Ent();
        ent.setImportantNumber(1);
        logger.info("Method A do sth and ...");
        ent.getSth();
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Testing</name>
    <description>App for tests</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.14.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>11</complianceLevel>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Your question is about IntelliJ IDEA when using AspectJ in a Maven project, not about AspectJ + Maven as such. I tried your code in IDEA 2021.2.3 (Ultimate Edition) and cannot reproduce the problem you describe. Whenever I edit the aspect, I can just run the same Spring Boot application again with `Ctrl-F5`, and the aspect gets re-compiled and re-woven. Did you install the AspectJ add-on in IDEA? Is something wrong in your Spring Boot application (you did not post it here)?

Comment: Besides, why are you using native AspectJ compile-time weaving in a Spring application instead of Spring AOP? You should have compelling reasons for doing so. I know that `call()` pointcuts are available in native AspectJ only, but you could simply use `execution()`, which would also weave fewer classes. Is your requirement to weave aspects into classes which are not Spring-managed beans/components?

Comment: Feedback, please. It is not very polite to ask a question and then not to react to questions asked by the people who volunteered to help you.

Comment: I didn't install AspectJ add-on in IDEA and my Spring Boot app works well.  I use aspectj to do aspect around method in class that is not Spring-managed bean. My intelliJ version is 2020.2 for some reason. When I compile file xxx.aj everythings works well, but there is a problem when I use java class and annotation @Aspect as in example above.

Comment: Spring AOP is not AspectJ. So if you want to use native AspectJ, install the add-on. Do not make a simple matter complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell where the problem is. normally you don't need to keep to maven clean install everytime you change something in your code.I suggest you use devtools maybe